# Is it a good idea to ask understanding-verification type of questions on this site?

Tags: discussion

In my process of studying math, I am often amased by how much different understandings of the same concept can really deepen one's comprehension. And I am also shocked by how much a wrong or incomplete understanding can slow down one's progress or even leads him/her to the wrong path. I am sure both cases have happened to everyone. But for the 2 months I've been on this site, I have hardly seen such problems. There's proof/solution-verification but no understanding-verification.

What I am picturing is: a poster asks a question, in which he/she states his/her understanding of a specific topic. If it is wrong, then other people can correct it; if it is incomplete, then other people can complete it or even enrich it with their own understanding.

I don't think this type of question violates any code of this site:

(1) Showing efforts: the poster must have been thinking to ask such questions

(2) Specific: it can be about the understanding of a very specific topic

(3) Answerable: it cannot be more "unanswerable" than proof/solution-verification type of questions

So why is it so rare? Is it not encouraged here or have people simply never thought of it?

Comment: Do you have any examples showing what "understanding-verification" means? The term "understanding" seems vague. Also, "incomplete" understanding may lead to poorly phrased questions.

Comment: I like this understanding-verification type of question a lot, and I'd like to see more of them.

Comment: @littleO Yes, me too. Do you think there's something we can do to encourage this?

Comment: I have personally posted a few such questions about difference sets.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Is it not encouraged here?

It is not discouraged, as far as I know. As long as it reasonably follows the advice on quality, it should be OK.

> have people simply never thought of it?

Obviously not so, since you did, and if you search "is my understanding" in the search bar you'll discover quite a few questions like that.

> So why is it so rare?

I don't think it is, except when compared to the proportion of non-understanding questions. I think there are probably a great deal of questions which ask this question implicitly as they struggle with a concrete problem. And there are quite a few that ask it explicitly.

I think the reason they are relatively rare is probably this: a preponderance of users are at the stage where they are more concerned with specific problems and not high-level views of concepts.  This is just a matter of their level of mathematical maturity.  As far as I know, this is completely normal from a developmental standpoint: becoming curious about conceptual correctness usually happens later in math education.

Comment: +1 I have asked a few questions which include "is my understanding correct?" and have received reasonably good answers.

Comment: Your answer makes perfect sense to me. Maybe I haven't seen many because I haven't been here for that long. Nonetheless, do you think maybe we can somehow encourage this, like maybe adding a tag?

Comment: @trisct People who follow the philosophy of tagging management better may correct me, but I think it is not a good idea for a tag. It could arguably be applied to a great percentage of questions. It does not really help organize questions by subject matter.  I don’t think tags should really be used to encourage posting behavior. I also don’t see why it needs to be particularly encouraged: it just happens naturally.

Comment: @trisct the closest thing we have may be [intuition], but I think that’s rather a legacy thing.